# Invoke on EDT or not

Tags: java, swing

I have a class name Foo that extends JFrame. The Foo class has several components and one object x as private fields and **those components never use object x or vice versa (means components are completely independent on x)**. Of course the instantiation of Foo class is placed inside EDT but situation is **I'm going to change value of object x from non EDT thread** like (Foo.x.getValue() == ..... ). Should it be placed inside EDT? If it's gonna look like this:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            foo.x.setValue(newValue);
        }
    });
```

Comment: If `x` is never accessed from the EDT, why is it a member of `Foo`? Is the instance referenced by `x` mutable?

Comment: Correct! X is mutable object reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only things which directly impact the GUI need to be performed on the EDT. Even if a variable is a member of a GUI object, it does not necessarily need to be accessed exclusively from the EDT. Since this is a member you've added yourself and you're sure that it doesn't interact with the GUI, you're free to change it in whatever thread you like.

Even if one of your components would read `x` to decide how it is displayed, you can modify `x` in any thread you like, as long as the GUI updates themselves are done on the EDT - just make sure `x` is `volatile` if it's used by multiple threads.

It does sound like `x` might belong somewhere else, though.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible that I can get JLabel.getText() from outside EDT since this method does not update any GUI? How about DefaultListModel, should any changes made on this model object be placed in EDT?

Comment: @FinalIllusion Modifications to a `ListModel` might not be safe. The default JList implementation doesn't display changes immediately - it notifies the UI and invokes `repaint()`, which will cause the component to be pained _by the EDT_. However, if it's already painting there could be problems with concurrent modifications (I'm not _sure_, but better safe than sorry... please correct me if you know more about this). So be careful with that. `getText` should be fine.

Comment: I'm not sure either :D. Let's get back to object x in my example, if I make some modification on object x inside class Foo(which is inside EDT) do i have to make new thread to make sure the modification is executed on non EDT thread or i just make direct modification inside class Foo (inside EDT)

Comment: @FinalIllusion Performing something simple on the EDT won't hurt you. Make sure that GUI tasks are done on the EDT. Make sure long-running tasks are done on a different thread. Other things can just be done wherever it's most convenient for you.

Comment: So is object x supposed to be volatile since it might be modified among threads (EDT and other threads) for my case ?

Comment: _If_ you use it from multiple threads, yes, otherwise your threads may interfere with each other, or you could fool the JVM into performing incorrect optimizations.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15273/discussion-between-final-illusion-and-jacob-raihle)

Answer (score 1):

If `x` is a UI element (JTextfield, JTable, javax.swing.*), then you'll need to use the EDT, just as you do in your example.

Otherwise, I don't see any restriction that would apply here.